# Is this how its supposed to work? I have a subscription payment confirmation REST endpoint, but anyone authenticated can access it

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, jwt

I'm using JWT authentication on my REST endpoints, but once you make an account you can opt to purchase a subscription.

However, the purchase endpoint is a POST to `/subscribe/new` and if anyone gets the jwt from session storage, they can pretty much make CURL request to the endpoint and purchase a subscription.

Is this how it is supposed to work?  How do I stop someone from just doing CURL to purchase a subscription?  Obviously they need to supply additional information in the body like their payment details and stuff, but if they do that then it will go through provided they have the token.

So if a bad person gets that JWT somehow from the user's session storage, they can pretty much wreak havoc right?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't avoid that someone post a request to your endpoint. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42586/ensure-web-service-only-accessed-by-authorized-applications

So assume it can happen and if it is a risk for you, be prepared:

- do not authorize access to the service with this JWT
- use an additional authentication factor for restricted operation:a password, an SMS, etc.
- request the needed data and validate it before authorize access: for example the credit card number